# Sin espacio tablespace: ORA-32771: cannot add file to bigfile tablespace

Tags: plsql, oracle-11g, tablas, oracle-sqldeveloper

Al parecer me acabo de quedar sin espacio en mi tablespace y no se como aumentar su tamaño, intenté con el siguiente comando:

```
ALTER TABLESPACE SANDRA ADD DATAFILE '/u01/oradata/userdata03.dbf' SIZE 3000M;
```

y me sale:

```
ORA-32771: cannot add file to bigfile tablespace
```

Ya no se con que mas probar. Si alguien pudiera decirme que hacer lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que hice para solucionar este problema fue irme a la opción *DBA*, abrir el TABLESPACE, darle a la opción *Editar* y ahí en *Editar Tablespace* asignarle un nuevo tamaño, en mi caso 2G, además de activar la ampliación automática.

Comment: En lugar de colocar _solucionado_, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un foro.